# Copying a file in visual basic

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am trying to copy a file from one folder to another in visual basic. I know the names of the directory of the file and the directory I want to move it to but I can't seem to get it to work. Any tips?

Edit: The file in the second folder needs to have the same name as the original and the original file must have its name changed to lmsimport

Comment: Give more information about what you've tried that hasn't worked.

Comment: A simple google [search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Copying+a+file+in+visual+basic&oq=Copying+a+file+in+visual+basic&aqs=chrome..69i57&client=ubuntu-browser&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) would have been suffice

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
File.Copy
```

Use this Sample:

```
Imports System.IO

Class Program
Private Shared Sub Main()
    String Currentlocation = "C:\test.txt"
    String Backuplocation = "C:\Backup\NewTest.txt"
    ' Copy one file to a nonexistent location
    File.Copy(Currentlocation, Backuplocation)
End Sub
```

End Class